# Inserting every child of a div after every 3rd child of another div in another container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the code below where the requirement is a div(in sequence) from second set should be placed after every 3rd child of first set using jquery.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>  
</div>

<div class="catalog">
  <div class="data"></div>
  <div class="data"></div>
  <div class="data"></div>
</div>
```

Desired Output:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="data"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="data"></div>
 <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="data"></div>    
</div>
```

I've tried the following code:

```
  $('.catalog').each(function(){
    var $divs = $(this).children('div');
      for(var i=0; i<$divs.length; i+=3){
        $('.row > div:nth-child(3n)').after($divs[i]);
      }                         
   })
```

This code is attaching the first div under catalog and not the remaining divs in the count.

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: ..and you have to **demonstrate** what you have tried..which you have now done.

Comment: @Paulie_D - I've included the code that I tried and failed to get it working. So please see if you can help. There is always a newbie trying to understand things and how to use the platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit complicated and not what you wants.
Use this jquery:

```
var i = 3;

$('.catalog div').each(function(index, el){
    var rowDivCounter = $('.row > div').length;
    if(i>=rowDivCounter){
        $('.row').append($(el));
    }
    else{
        $('.row > div:nth-child('+ i +')').after($(el));                
        i = i + 3 + index + 1;
    }

});
```

You need to count line this. First element is the 3. you want the catalog div after it, then you need the 6. but the code already insert catalog div so 7. so need to add the loop (index + 1) to get this. And so on.